# log 5xx errors in varnishlog, but no higher than "599"

Tags: varnish

Having searched on the internet I found this solution to identify 5xx status codes:

> varnishlog -q "RespStatus >=500"

The problem with this is that it also includes internal codes such as 750 or 850, and I don't need that, as those are not problematic.
I also tried the following, with no avail:

> varnishlog -q "RespStatus >=500 and RespStatus <599"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just regex it:

```
varnishlog -q "RespStatus ~ '5[0-9][0-9]'"
```

Comment: Quite an obvious answer, yes, given the fact that that's what ~ introduces, regex. Thanks for the tip! :)